How to implement interface with reflect in golang
there is a interface here
type itr interface {
    pt()
}

i want to implement the interface with reflect now
func main() {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(itr{})
    // 通过类型创建一个结构体对象
    v := reflect.New(t)
    // 设置字段值
    fmt.Println(v.NumMethod())
}

but it will wrong in reflect.TypeOf(itr{})
i try to change the code
func main() {
    var a itr
    t := reflect.TypeOf(a)
    // 通过类型创建一个结构体对象
    v := reflect.New(t)
    // 设置字段值
    fmt.Println(v.NumMethod())
}

it still wrong because the 't' is nil
i wang to get a unname struct implement the interface

If you want to get the type descriptor of an interface type, use reflect.TypeOf((*itr)(nil)).Elem(). If you need an anonymous struct implementing such interface, use struct{itr}. If you want something sensible, please describe what you want to achieve.

see icza's answer, but as a general thing: You cannot create an instance of an interface. An interface is just a promise that some (other) type has certain methods. If you were to call methods on such a empty interface instance, what would you expect to happen?
E.g. if you were to take icza's code with the embedded interface in an anonymous struct, then this will please the compiler, but it will throw a nil panic as soon as someone tries to call these methods

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to generate an instance of the interface in dynamic runtime.it is my goal that wrap some base function's code in generate function, For callers, they just pass the complicated functions in generate function.the generate function will build an instance of interface.
